# Habilitar/Desabilitar botão de acordo com a validação de campos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5, jquery-validate

Estou realizando a validação de data para dois campos `<input type="text">` com o [`jQueryFormValidator`](http://formvalidator.net/):

```js
        $.validate({
            modules : 'date'
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.1.47/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>

<form>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Tdesl"  maxlength="10" data-validation="date" data-validation-format="dd/mm/yyyy" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa" OnKeyPress="formatar('##/##/####', this)" id="Cdesl22"></label>

    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-validation="date" data-validation-format="dd/mm/yyyy" maxlength="10" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa" OnKeyPress="formatar('##/##/####', this)" name="Tinsem3" id="Cinsem"></label>

</form>
```

Mas não consigo fazer com que, ao serem validados esses campos, que um botão (`<button="button">` não é um `submit`) seja habilitado.

Segundo algumas respostas que vi no SOen, o [`jQueryFormValidator`](http://formvalidator.net/) não tem suporte nativo pra esta função, então estou tentando adaptar [esse script](http://jsfiddle.net/x25pv/) (o link é do FIDDLE, mas achei pelo SOen):

```js
    $('#myform > input').on('input', function () {
        var empty = false;
        $('form > input, form > select').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });
    
        if (empty) {
            $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">Username
    <br />
    <input type="text" class="class" id="user_input" name="username" />
    <br />Password
    <br />
    <input type="password" id="pass_input" name="password" />
    <br />Confirm Password
    <br />
    <input type="password" id="v_pass_input" name="v_password" />
    <br />Email
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
    <br />Birthday
    <br />
    <input type="date" id="bday" name="birthday" />
    <br />Sex
    <br />
    <select name="sex" id="sex">
        <option>Male</option>
        <option>female</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

Contudo, este script requer que todos os campos `input` sejam preenchidos, e preciso que sejam apenas dois (existem mais campos no formulário, e preciso que apenas dois deles sejam observados). Tentei criar uma classe pra aplicar nestes dois campos, mas acho que não fiz direito:

```
$('#myform > .classinput').on('input', function () {
```

Além disso, este script usa o type `date`, enquanto no meu caso estou utilizando campos do type `text`, mas que estão sendo validados para data, então se fosse possível utilizar o resultado da validação (pra habilitar o botão) seria o ideal, mas senão der pode ser apenas com as regras básicas, tipo aceitar para o dia no máximo 31, no mês 12, no ano 2015, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Vejamos

De jQuery não entendo quase nada - prefiro o meu código em *JavaScript* puro (sem *frameworks*). Acabei por  aprender um bocado de *jQuery* tentando solucionar seu problema. E no final, acho que foi solucionado..

---

### Explicação

Segue uma breve explicação do código e do processo. Talvez facilite o entendimento.

**No JS**

- Adicionei o `$.validate();` pois precisava verificar se a checagem da data funcionava corretamente com o código, obviamente;
- Em `$.validate();`, adicionei o `return(false)` para impedir o envio do formulário no caso de haver outras checagens de outros elementos do formulário;
- Dentro do escopo de `$('form > .checarData')`, acresci o `.on('validation', ...` para que houvesse uma forma de determinar a ativação do botão;

**No HTML**

- o elemento de ID `#aniv2` serve como espelho do elemento de ID `#aniv1`. Ou seja, o que tiver em `#aniv1` terá em `#aniv2`.

No caso, quantas mais datas a a serem validadas você tive, cada uma delas terá que ter um elemento espelho. **Por quê?**

***Veja***: o *jQuery Form Validator* precisa que o atributo `type` seja igual a `text` como você mesmo disse. **MAS**, depois que o formulário for enviado, você vai precisar que ele seja do tipo `date`.

**Assim**, tendo os dois elementos, sendo um espelho do outro, *você consegue validar a data e ainda assim obter o formulário com o campo 'aniversário' do tipo `date` para formatar na página destino, seja qual for*. E como um deles está oculto, o usuário não irá enxergar esse elemento espelho.

---

### Código & Exemplo

```js
$.validate({
    modules: 'date',
    onSuccess: function () {

        /* Impede o envio do formulário */
        return (false);

    }
});

/* 'form' é a TAG mesmo */
$('form > .checarData').on('validation', function (evt, valid) {

    /* Copia #aniv1 em #aniv2 */
    document.getElementById("aniv2").value = document.getElementById("aniv1").value;
    
    /* Verifica se o campo não está vazio E SE a data está OK */
    if (valid) {
        $('#registrar').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#registrar').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.1.47/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>

<form id="formulario">

  Usuário
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="user" name="username" />

  <br />Email
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />

  <br />Aniversário
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="aniv1" name="aniv1" class="checarData" data-validation="birthdate" data-validation-format="dd/mm/yyyy" />

  <!-- Espelho de #aniv1, porém do tipo "date" -->
  <input type="date" id="aniv2" name="aniv2" hidden="hidden" />

  <br />

  <input type="button" id="registrar" value="Registrar" disabled="disabled" />

</form>
```

---

### Notas

Você deve entender de *jQuery* o suficiente para saber como inserir o `.on('input', ...` no lugar de `.on('blur', ...`. Eu realmente não sou o mestre nesse *framework* e nunca usei ele diretamente profissionalmente - somente quando aparece em bibliotecas de terceiros em sistemas não desenvolvidos por mim.

Ah! Por via das dúvidas, [JSFiddle](https://goo.gl/hIyWtO) para garantir!

**Espero ter ajudado!**

Comment: Cara, com certeza vai ajudar muito! +1 Só as explicações que vc deu já me ajudaram a entender muita coisa aqui... Tô estudando o código e tentando implementar, mas não tenho conhecimento profundo em jQuery não (sou bem iniciante aliás)... Vou passando aqui o resultados... Valeu mesmo!

Comment: Então, ele faz a validação da data no campo text, mas não habilita o botão. Mesmo no JsFiddle, ou no exemplo acima, não está funcionando a habilitação. Estou fazendo uns testes aqui, mas não preciso que verifique se o campo está vazio, se ele estiver com a data certa, não precisa verificar se está vazio (nenhum, só o de data mesmo). Não entendi muito bem o porque dos campos input com hidden... inspecionando pelo navegador dá pra ver a tag form modificando de error pra has-sucess, quando valida... não dá pra usar isso como parâmetro pra habilitar o botão, isto é, se for has-sucess habilita?

Comment: Isso que falei de ver a tag form alterando pra has success é no chrome, em Elements.

Comment: Valeu ae José, adaptei aqui e funcionou, postei uma resposta pra mostrar o que fiz, dá uma olhada pra ver se tem algo que possa melhorar... Abraços.

Comment: Eu dei uma olhada no que você falou.

A verificação de campos em branco está presente pois estava no código original da pergunta. Mas se não precisa, basta remover a classe `checar` dos elementos de formulário. E se não for nunca usar, comenta que eu edito o código.

Os problemas do Google Chrome: testei no Chromium. Verifiquei que o problema é que o navegador não permite incluir o arquivo *.js referente ao *jQuery*. É relacionado a ser um endereço Secure HTTP (https) porém a requisição não é de fato segura. Assim, eles bloqueiam e o código não valida pois nada do jQuery existe!

Comment: Então, dá uma olhada na resposta que postei agora, consegui colocar um exemplo funcional no snippet aqui do SOpt. O código ficou bem pequeno, legal, mas ainda não entendo porque tenho que passar por 3 inputs (o que estou fazendo)... De qualquer forma valeu mesmo, além da solução vc explicou legal...

Comment: Alterei a resposta, e reduzi um pouco mais o código. Ele só estava grande por que eu achei que precisasse haver a checagem dos campos em branco que requeria a conversa de variáveis de dois escopos diferentes sem a aparente possibilidade de usar variáveis globais. Acabou por eliminar um elemento oculto que servia de uma espécie de *variável global*. Resumindo: o escopo do jQuery não estava me permitindo criar globais dentro do *JSFiddle* ou o *snippet* do *StackOverflow*. Ou seja, usando um elemento oculto para armazenar dados, burlei o escopo das variáveis "do jQuery"! :) Mas não precisa mais.

Comment: Cara, muito bom, já tá funcionando, eu já entendi a maior parte, e quase nem tenho mais cara de perguntar nada haha, mas ainda não consegui entender como aniv1 se torna espelho de aniv2, e como validou pega os dados de aniv2 (entendi que é importante, e tá perfeito aqui, até a leitura dos dados pelo PHP, perfeito...). É só porque o input está logo embaixo e com hidden? Ou tem algo oculto no js que faz isso?

Comment: Ah.. Entendi sua dúvida! É que, como bem sabe, você pode acessar os elementos por JS, certo? Essa linha: `document.getElementById("aniv2").value = document.getElementById("aniv1").value;` pega o conteúdo do elemento com id `#aniv1` e joga em `#aniv2`. Fiz isso porque você pediu para ter o `type="date"` e o `type="text"`. Eu acho que não faria diferença e acho que você pode testar só com um `#aniv` além de remover essa linha do JS. Mas para ter certeza, você tem que testar na sua aplicação. *Nota*: editei e comentei o código para explicar o *'efeito espelho'*.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24287/discussion-between-jose-and-gustavox).

Answer (score 2):

Fiz uma alteração com a classe `obrig` para os campos validados:

```js
$('#myform > input').on('input', function () {
    var empty = false;
    $('form > .obrig').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '' ) {
            empty = true;
        }else {
            empty = false;
        }
    });
     if (empty) {
        $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">Username
    <br />
    <input type="text" class="obrig" id="user_input" name="username" />
    <br />Password
    <br />
    <input type="password" class="obrig"  id="pass_input" name="password" />
    <br />Confirm Password
    <br />
    <input type="password" id="v_pass_input" name="v_password" />
    <br />Email
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
    <br />Birthday
    <br />
    <input type="date" class='obrig' id="bday" name="birthday" />
    <br />Sex
    <br />
    <select name="sex" id="sex">
        <option>Male</option>
        <option>female</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

Comment: Legal +1, agora falta só validar o campo como data antes de habilitar o botão.

Comment: coloca a class='obrig' que resolve

Comment: Então, mas o campo é `text`, e tem que ser validado pra data antes de abrir o botão. Neste caso ele só vai requerer que tenha qualquer preenchimento, como se fosse um campo de texto, e preciso que ou ele pegue pela validação que to usando (form-validator), ou que faça uma outra, mas que qualquer forma ele valide que é uma data correta antes de habilitar o botão...