# Como converter função .on do jQuery para JavaScript puro

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

Hoje comecei a tentar transformar uma função que estou usando em jQuery (que o @José me ajudou implementar [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66556/23400)) a `.on`, para JavaScript puro, mas estou enfrentando algumas dificuldades. Os cursos on line que já fiz não abordaram este aspecto, então se a solução viesse acompanhada de uma boa explicação seria ideal.

O código em jQuery é este:

```
$('.checar').on('validation', function(evt, valid) {
    var validou = document.getElementById('validou').value = valid ? "true" : "false";

    if (validou === "true") {
        $('#startBtnseg').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Esse código faz a validação de uma data, utilizando os parâmetros retornados pelo [`form.validator`](http://formvalidator.net/), e se a data é validada, ele retira o `disabled` do `button`.

Estou tentando utilizar `addEventListener()`, mas não está funcionando.

Fiz um [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gustavox/107unza1/2/) pra demonstrar o problema, e basta retirar o jQuery (apagar ou comentar) pra ver que o Javascript puro passa a habilitar o botão normalmente, mas se o jQuery está junto, daí não funciona.

Eu não preciso que ele utilize classe ('checar'), porque quero usar este script em conjunto com outro, que já vem funcionando para a mesma coisa (retirar o `disabled` do mesmo botão), este em JavaScript puro (que eu adaptei do script que @Sérgio escreveu [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/67850/23400)).

Separadamente os dois scripts funcionam perfeitamente, mas quando os dois estão presentes, o de javascript puro não faz diferença, e se valida o código jQuery, então ele abre o `button` (não importando que a condição do JavaScript puro não esteja cumprida).

O quero é "fundir" estes dois scripts, mas gostaria também de entender o processo de conversão da função para Javascript puro, se fosse possível.

O código JavaScript puro da outra validação:

```
var datainicial = document.getElementById('Cinsem');
var datafinal = document.getElementById('Cdesl22');

function formatar(mascara, documento) {
    var i = documento.value.length;
    var saida = mascara.substring(0, 1);
    var texto = mascara.substring(i);
    if (texto.substring(0, 1) != saida) {
        documento.value += texto.substring(0, 1);
    }
    verificar();
}

function gerarData(str) {
    var partes = str.split("/");
    return new Date(partes[2], partes[1] - 1, partes[0]);
}

function verificar() {
    var inicio = datainicial.value;
    var fim = datafinal.value;

    if (inicio.length != 10 || fim.length != 10) {
        return;
    }
    if (gerarData(fim) >= gerarData(inicio)) {
        $('#startBtnseg').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normalmente converter do `on` para JavaScript nativo é simples - para cada evento tratado pelo `on` (ex.: `click`, `blur`, `keyup`) há uma funcionalidade nativa correspondente (ex.: `onclick`, `onblur`, `onkeyup`); pode-se então atribuir uma função tratadora (*handler*) aos elementos desejados (ou a algum ancestral comum dos mesmos, no espírito da função `on`) ou usar `addEventListener`, como sugerido na própria pergunta.

Entretanto, esse `validate` implementado pelo plugin `form.validator` não tem um correspondente nativo que possa ser facilmente chamado [que eu saiba]. Para implementar uma funcionalidade equivalente, só mesmo vendo o que o plugin faz (talvez estudando seu código fonte) e fazendo igual ou parecido. De modo que não tenho uma resposta pra te dar nesse caso.

Entretanto, se for só para garantir que ambas as verificações (formato e lógica customizada) sejam feitas, pode-se dar um jeito. Não conheço o `form.validator` com detalhes, então não sei qual a melhor forma de fazer isso (com certeza tem algo na API pra te ajudar). Mas uma maneira - nem um pouco "polida", entretanto - é modificar seu `formatar` para ativar (*trigger*) programaticamente o `validate`, e *no próprio validate* chamar o seu método `verificar`:

```
on('validation', function (evt, valid) {
    var validou =  document.getElementById('validou').value = valid ? "true" : "false";

    if (validou === "true") {
        verificar(); // Chama o verificar também, em vez de liberar o botão
    }
});

...

function formatar(mascara, documento) {
    var i = documento.value.length;
    var saida = mascara.substring(0, 1);
    var texto = mascara.substring(i);
    if (texto.substring(0, 1) != saida) {
        documento.value += texto.substring(0, 1);
    }
    $(documento).validate(); // trigger no validate
}
```

O resultado é que o botão só se tornará habilitado quando ambas as condições forem satisfeitas. [Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/107unza1/3/).

Comment: Nossa, excelente resposta!  O primeiro e o terceiro objetivos (fazer ambas as validações e APRENDER NO PROCESSO) estão satisfeitos! :-)  Pelo que vc explicou não é a melhor prática, então vou me segurar pra não clicar no resolvido :-), e deixar aberta por enquanto, vai que aparece alguém pra contribuir ainda mais né. Valeu demais cara! Muito sucesso pra ti! Abraços!